# Model for multiclass & multilabel classification in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to perform a classification task with sklearn in python. 
The problems that I am facing are mostly due because of the structure of training data which I've found online. 
This is an example of my training set:

[image: training set]

Where opos, oneg, iro are respectively: positive sentiment, negative sentiment, irony.
What I would like to do is to train a model which will take a text as input and give as output those three values.

Ideally, what I'd like to happen is that if I give as input a negative and ironic sentence my output should look something like opos = 0, oneg = 1, iro = 1

Now, I've already managed to classify over a single label using a logistic regressor (I've managed to classify if a sentence is positive or not) but I have not idea on how to perform this kind of classification.

`model.fit(x_train, y_train)`

Where x_train contains the TFIDF representation for my text and the y_train contains the values of my 'opos' label.

The problem is that I don't know how to fit the model with all of the three labels ['opos','oneg','iro'].

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of data? Are you trying to use a NN or something else? In general, I would think you want to do something like TFIDF (there is a whole package on this in sklearn), to pick out the words that make each text unique. You could then train on those words, or imbed those words within a context vector (like word2vec).

Comment: there is a `multi_class` option in the sklearn linear regression function.. check that..

Comment: Yes, I've already applied TFIDF to my data. What I can't figure out is how to properly fit the model with more than one label since my labels are in three different columns of my training set.

I've managed to fit my model with just one label as follows:

```model.fit(x_train, y_train)```

Where x_train contains the TFIDF representation of my text and my y_train contains my 'opos' label. 

How can I fit the model with all of those three labels?
Thank you.

Comment: why not have two model do the job? one for classifying the sentiment an other for identifying whether it is a irony or not